# Concat multiple columns of a dataframe using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a list of columns, for example:

```python
col_list = ['col1','col2']
df = spark.read.json(path_to_file)
print(df.columns)
# ['col1','col2','col3']
```

I need to create a new column by concatenating `col1` and `col2`. I don't want to hard code the column names while concatenating but need to pick it from the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) to `concatenate` as many columns as you specify in your `list`. Keep on passing them as arguments.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat
# Creating an example DataFrame
values = [('A1',11,'A3','A4'),('B1',22,'B3','B4'),('C1',33,'C3','C4')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|  A1|  11|  A3|  A4|
|  B1|  22|  B3|  B4|
|  C1|  33|  C3|  C4|
+----+----+----+----+
```

In the `concat()` function, you pass all the columns you need to concatenate - like `concat('col1','col2')`. If you have a list, you can `un-list` it using `*`. So `(*['col1','col2'])` returns `('col1','col2')`

```python
col_list = ['col1','col2']
df = df.withColumn('concatenated_cols',concat(*col_list))
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+-----------------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|concatenated_cols|
+----+----+----+----+-----------------+
|  A1|  11|  A3|  A4|             A111|
|  B1|  22|  B3|  B4|             B122|
|  C1|  33|  C3|  C4|             C133|
+----+----+----+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: can we have a delimiter in between

Comment: @G.v.Sridhar you can use something like this concat(col("a"), lit(" "), col("b")) and in lit() you can put your delimiter

Comment: If you want a delimiter, use concat_ws, like this (* is the delimiter):

df = df.withColumn('concatenated_cols',concat_ws('*',*col_list))

Comment: when I use concat_ws(",", *col_list), it returns "_1" as col heading instead of "concatenated_cols" and the value becomes Row(concatenated_cols='A1,11,A3,A4) .. how do I fix this ?